# Which planar subgraph of hypercube Q4 has the maximum number of edges?

Tags: graph-theory, hypergraphs

I believe Q3 is the biggest planar subgraph of Q4, but I think that by drawing four edges at the outermost vertices of Q3 I can obtain a bigger subgraph. Am I thinking correctly?

Comment: I don't have the answer, but some thoughts: $Q_4$ has girth 4, so a well-known corollary of Euler's formula gives that a planar subgraph of $Q_4$ has at most $2(2^4) - 4 = 28$ edges (i.e. we cannot possibly do better than this). Additionally, viewing $Q_4$ as $Q_3 \square K_2$ (I think this is the same way you're thinking about it), it is pretty clear that we can add some more edges to $Q_3$ while maintaining planarity (as I think you noted). Hence $Q_3$ is not an edge-maximal planar subgraph of $Q_4$. Finding exactly where the answer lies within this range is now the challenge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Paralyzed_by_Time [showed](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3724769/which-planar-subgraph-of-hypercube-q4-has-the-maximum-number-of-edges#comment7658504_3724769) that a required subgraph has at most $28$ edges, it remains to match this upper bound by an example. For this note that $Q_4=Q_2\times Q_2$, where pairs $(v,u)$ and $(v’,u’)$ in the product are adjacent iff ($v=v’$ and $u$ is adjacent to $u’$) or ($v$ ia adjacent to $v’$ and $u=u’$).  Let $Q’_2$ be the graph $Q_2$ with an edge removed. Then a graph $Q_4=Q_2\times Q’_2$ has $28$ edges and can be drawn in a plane with four nested cycles of order $4$.